# 400 Bad Request API CALL when using Clarifai's API with react's useState and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, callback, use-effect, use-state, clarifai

Trying to build an app that recognizes faces and objects in an image using clarifai's Api through react-dropzone which is a drag and drop package that i installed. when i use a static image i get a response from Clarifai with out any errors but when i try to load it from my state i keep getting 400 bad request.

I think the error might has to do with the way useState works.

Please can anyone give some help?

see the code below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

import Header from './components/header/header.component.jsx';
import Modal from './components/modal/modal.component';
import Box from './components/box/box.component';
import './App.css';


    const app = new Clarifai.App({
        apiKey: 'REDACTED'
    
    });

const App = () => {

    const [fileProperties, setFileProperties] = useState([]);
    const [isModalOpen, setModal] = useState(false);

    const handleDrop = acceptedFiles => {
        setFileProperties(acceptedFiles.map(file => URL.createObjectURL(file)));
        toggleModal()
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if(fileProperties.length > 0){
            console.log(fileProperties);
            app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, fileProperties).then(
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log('There was an error', err);
            }
                );          
        }
    }, [fileProperties]);

        

    const toggleModal = () => {
        setModal(!isModalOpen);
    }
    return (
        <div className="main">  
            <Header/>   
            { isModalOpen && 
                <Modal>
                    <Box isModalOpen={isModalOpen} fileProperties={fileProperties} toggleModal={toggleModal}/>
                </Modal>
            }   
            <Dropzone  onDrop={handleDrop} accept="image/*">
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject}) => {
                  // additional CSS depends on dragging status
                  const additionalClass = isDragAccept ? "accept" : isDragReject ? "reject" : "";
                  return (
                    <div{...getRootProps({className: `dropzone ${additionalClass}` })} >
                          <input {...getInputProps()} />
                          <h2>This smart box detects faces & objects like sunglasses and hats in an image</h2>
                          <span>{isDragActive ? "" : ""}</span>
                          <p>Drag and drop an image, or click to select </p>
                    </div>
                  );
               }}
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    );  
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

URL.createObjectURL returns DOMString, you need to send base64 string or url that Clarifai can access.
https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/predict/images

Comment: after console.loging i see that it generated this
["blob:http://localhost:3000/02c24c62-9dd0-43e7-a72e-2d524ec526c2"].
how can i convert it to base64 then?